# [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <network> - did you register the component correctly? vue-social-share

Tags: vuejs2

Trying to use the vue-social-sharing (latest version 2.4.3) library but keep getting the following:

**[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.**

I've followed the guides looked at code examples. But, can't seem to figure out what I'm missing or getting wrong.

I've created a separate component and just followed the sample provided by vue-social-share. But still keep getting the error.

Here is my main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import './plugins/vuetify'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'



Vue.config.productionTip = false;

let SocialSharing = require('vue-social-sharing');
Vue.use(SocialSharing);

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

Here is my component (SocialSharingTest.vue):

```html
<template>
<social-sharing url="https://vuejs.org/"
                      title="The Progressive JavaScript Framework"
                      description="Intuitive, Fast and Composable MVVM for building interactive interfaces."
                      quote="Vue is a progressive framework for building user interfaces."
                      hashtags="vuejs,javascript,framework"
                      twitter-user="vuejs"
                      inline-template>
  <div>
      <network network="email">
          <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Email
      </network>
      <network network="facebook">
        <v-icon class="mr-3" style="color: #3b5998">fab fa-facebook</v-icon>
      </network>
      <network network="googleplus">
        <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i> Google +
      </network>

  </div>
</social-sharing>
</template>
<script>


  export default {
    name: "SocialSharingTest",
  }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Component isn't working as expected and keeping getting the **[Vue Warn] as described above. I see a working example here for what I would expect to see:

https://codesandbox.io/s/3yv7q36lq?from-embed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import SocialSharing from 'vue-social-sharing';

import Vue from 'vue'
const VueSelect = {
  install(Vue, options) {
    Vue.component('SocialSharing', SocialSharing)
  }
};
Vue.use(VueSelect)
```

Can you try this and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you register component globally:

```
const SocialSharing = require('vue-social-sharing');
Vue.component('social-sharing', SocialSharing)
```

[vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html)

Comment: Thanks. Still seem to be getting the same thing: **[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <network> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.**

Answer (score 0):

I also started to receive a **[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: v-icon**  on this component only (not in other components that use v-icon). To fix that to my main.js I added:

```
const Vuetify = require('vuetify');
Vue.use(Vuetify);
```

But now trying to incorporate social-sharing into a component that I already had created is giving me **[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.**

Haven't looked into that much yet. Might have something to do with Vuetify (I'm trying to include  into a ? I'll keep digging for what is happening there, but will take any help if someone knows what it could be.

Thanks. Just to be clear the above worked for original issue. It all seems to work within its own component, just not working as I would expect when trying to incorporate into the component I wish to use it in.

**UPDATE** - all working for the above I simply didn't include **inline-template** in my social sharing tag like:

```html
<social-sharing url="https://vuejs.org/" inline-template>
```